# Books for Anyone Regarding the complex nature of Varna

Tags: caste-system, varna, varnashrama, caste

I want books not modern ones, but ones by authentic religious personalities from olden times on the system of Varna and their differentitation of bodily and mental gunas. I would prefer a more universally accepted scripture such as dharmashastras, but Advaita and Vishistadvaita treatsies will do as well. Please make sure that it is complete and detailed guide.